# Pandas - How to count multiple columns and generate a percentage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has 100+ columns. The columns have either a 1 (for yes) and 0 (for no) as seen below.

[image]

I'm trying to find out the percentage of each - such as "what percentage of the episodes have a barn?" or "what percentage of the episodes have a beach?" I think I'll need to iterate through the rows and put these in buckets, but I'm wondering how. The total number of episodes is 381, which I know I'll need to find the total percentage of each. The end product should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you mean?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,1],[0,0,1]],
                  columns=['barn','beach','boat'])

>>> df
'''
   barn  beach  boat
0     1      1     0
1     0      0     1
2     1      0     1
3     0      0     1
'''

>>> df.mean().reset_index(name='value')
'''
   index  value
0   barn   0.50
1  beach   0.25
2   boat   0.75
```